# react-window set item size according to content height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, resize, react-window

I'm using react-window to implement a chat message list, but I'm getting stuck trying to set the right `itemSize` to each item. Happens that a chat message, based on his text length and window width, hasn't always a prefixed height (or a height that i can calculate in a simple way).

I'm currently using a `VariableSizeList` and the code looks like this

```
<AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => (
       <List
        height={height}
        itemCount={messages.length}
        itemSize={(index) => messages[index].isReply ? 118 : 79} /* THIS IS CURRENTLY WRONG, DOESN'T PICK ALL CASES!*/
        width={width}
       >
         {({ index, style }) => (
           <ChatMessage
            key={index}
            style={style}
            ...
           />
         )}
       </List>
    )}
```

Is there a way to set the item height of the list row equal to the ACTUAL height of its content?

Comment: Did you ever found a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

That's a little tricky and not officially supported by `react-window` as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window/issues/190). Apparantly one way to trick this is by using `Element.getBoundingClientRect().height` and setting the size of this `Element` via `itemSize`. An example is given here https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-size-of-react-window-list-items-64o9p?file=/src/ChatMessage.js